# How to modify the URI routing for a MVC PHP site?

Tags: php, apache, model-view-controller, mod-rewrite, uri

I'm trying rewrite an ASP.NET MVC 2 site I built using PHP/Apache for fun.

I've built a basic MVC framework which serves requests.  The request are executed through index.php?controller=&action=&otherstuff=123123

I'd like to be able to navigate my site by typing in /controller/action?otherstuff=123123

The webhost supports mod_rewrite, can I set this up using a .htaccess file in the same location as the index.php script?  How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'd recommend that you use the [Query String Append / qsa](http://www.purpleslurple.net/ps.php?theurl=http%3A%2F%2Fhttpd.apache.org%2Fdocs%2Fcurrent%2Fmod%2Fmod_rewrite.html#purp1279) directive. This means that if a query string is not passed, your rewrite will continue to work just fine.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2 [qsa,last]
```

This way, if you decide to use more query strings later, just go ahead - it will pass them.

G

Comment: thanks.  I did get it working with a small adjustment to the the rule you posted.  `RewriteRule ^(.[^/]*)/(.[^/]*)[/]?$ /index.php?controller=$1&action=$2 [L,QSA]`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?otherstuff=(.*)^ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&otherstuff=$3 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I'm using.  The framework parses the route.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
    RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
</IfModule>
```